# Import statement breaks in class-containing module when importing the class from different files

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my directory structure:

```
app
   -Folder1
       -class-container.py
       -queries.py
       -script.py
   -Folder2
   -Folder3
   -main.py
```

In my class-container file I import the SQL queries from queries.py with `from Folder1.queries import sql_queries`
When I import and use the class in main.py everything runs smoothly. But when I do the same from script.py I get a ModuleNotFoundError... no module named Folder1. I've tried relative imports and changing it to `from queries import sql_queries` but every time I change it, it breaks one or the other. Any insight would be valuable. Thanks!

Comment: For a relative import, the syntax would be `from .queries import sql_queries` (take note of the period).

Comment: Also, it's helpful to know if `script.py` is purely a script or if there are any other python files that import it as a module (with some form of `import script`)

Comment: I tried the from .queries import sql_queries but it breaks when I run it from the script.py. Specifically, I get an ImportError attempted relative import with no known parent package. Also, the script.py is purely a script, it isn't imported from any other python files.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/11443248) regarding Python relative imports